# Taking the prefix of a column value in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to select a column value and trim away a suffix matching a regular expression, all inside PostgreSQL, how can this be done?

Comment: Please show us an example of the input values and your expected output

Answer (score 1):

```
-- somewhat like performing s/_bar$// on "foo_bar"
select regexp_replace('foo_bar', '_bar$', '')
```